# PayPal preapproval mobile view

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm successfully registering and receiving back a preapproval key with PayPal using the preapproval workflow as per: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/

However, when I follow step 2:

> Step 2: Redirect the Customer to PayPal for Authorization
>
> To redirect the customer for authorization, use the preapproval key from the Preapproval response (Step 1), with the PayPal authorization URL:
>
> https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-preapproval&preapprovalkey=InsertPreapprovalKeyHere

When our customer is redirected to this URL on a mobile device, the resulting screen is showing as a desktop view, as opposed to the mobile view. Is this a sandbox-only issue or is this workflow not available on mobile?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Ryan,

Did you ever find a solution for this?

It looks like in the docs there is no mobile version of this.  PS not sure why a mod deleted this.. it seems valid to ask if the asker has the answer after 6 months have passed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below mentioned url for paypal preapproval mobile view:

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/preapproval?preapprovalKey=PA-xxxxxxxxxxxx&expType=mini

For Sandbox

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/preapproval?preapprovalKey=PA-xxxxxxxxxxxx&expType=mini